# Can we set Custom boundary for Multipart file upload in Spring Rest Template

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data, resttemplate, multipart

I want to create a custom boundary to send some json data and some file using Spring Rest template. I am not able to add that custom boundary.I am not able to override the default behavior of getting some random String for the boundary value. Below is my code snippet. Can some one suggest on how to get the custom boundary ?

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_MIXED);
    headers.set("boundary", "MyCustomboundary");
    headers.set("accepts", "multipart/mixed");


    MultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartRequest = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
```

'creating an HttpEntity for the JSON part'

```
    HttpHeaders jsonHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    jsonHeader.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    jsonHeader.set( "Content-Disposition","form-data");
    jsonHeader.set("boundary", "MyCustomboundary");
    jsonHeader.set( "name","Metadata");

    ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition
            .builder("form-data")
            .name("file")
            .filename("FileName"))
            .build();

    JSONObject json = getJSONObject();
    HttpEntity<String> jsonHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(json.toString(), jsonHeader);
```

'creating an HttpEntity for the binary part'

```
    HttpHeaders pictureHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    pictureHeader.set( "Content-Disposition","form-data");
    pictureHeader.set( "name","Content");
    pictureHeader.set("filename","FileNameTest");
    pictureHeader.set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    pictureHeader.set("boundary", "MyCustomboundary");

    HttpEntity<ByteArrayResource> picturePart = new HttpEntity<>(new ByteArrayResource(multipartFile.getBytes()), pictureHeader);
```

' putting the two parts in one request'

```
    multipartRequest.add("myAwesomeJsonData", jsonHttpEntity);
    multipartRequest.add("file", picturePart);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(multipartRequest, headers);


    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                                                    endPointURL,
                                                    HttpMethod.POST,
                                                    requestEntity,
                                                    String.class);
```

**OutPut Comes like this **

--xASRP9GvA7MfYQqgq0eVyQ2s1HCwMxm

Content-Disposition: form-data
Content-Type: application/json
boundary: MyCustomboundary
name: Metadata
Content-Length: 359

{"JSON Key":"Value"}
--xASRP9GvA7MfYQqgq0eVyQ2s1HCwMxm

Content-Disposition: form-data
name: Content
filename: output.pdf
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
boundary: MyCustomboundary
Content-Length: 4504

<-- File Content -->

--xASRP9GvA7MfYQqgq0eVyQ2s1HCwMxm--

**But I want it to be **

--MyCustomboundary

Content-Disposition: form-data
Content-Type: application/json
boundary: MyCustomboundary
name: Metadata
Content-Length: 359

{"JSON Key":"Value"}
--MyCustomboundary

Content-Disposition: form-data
name: Content
filename: output.pdf
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
boundary: MyCustomboundary
Content-Length: 4504

<-- File Content -->

--MyCustomboundary--

'Can some one suggest how to add this custom boundary ?'